# Encode URL for Kibana query string

Tags: url, kibana, encode, grafana

In my Grafana dashboard I've got a table which, if the user clicks on an item of it, does a redirect on Kibana passing via URL the value of ${__cell}, which represents the item clicked. It works everytime excepts if that item has a apostrophe ('): in that case the Item's name (let's say **Identita' Digitale**) is being passed via URL as `Identita%26%2339;%20Digitale`, and on Kibana is displayed as `Identita&#39; Digitale`.

I'm writing a Chrome extension that checks if the URL contains `Identita%26%2339;%20Digitale` and in that case does a redirect on Kibana using an encoded URL.

My problem is that I don't know how to encode it avoiding the **Unable to parse URL** Kibana error. I've tried everything: **\'**, **%27%20**, `&#39;` etc. but still get that error

Comment: use ${__cell:raw}, so you will have raw value in URL and then some encoding function - maybe encodeURI

Comment: Solved creating the Google Chrome Extension. In Kibana I've created a filter with Identita' Digitale just to see how the URL would change, then I've used that URL in my extension